# Variance and regression of binary repeated measures

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, binary-data, manova

For my research I have asked the same binary question (yes/no) to the same sample five times under different conditions. So every subject goes through every treatment. I have used a McNemar Chi-Square to present the statistical differences. Now I would like to test variance and use regression.

For variance between the different treatments I am not sure which test to use. The outcomes are binary and are thus repeated measures. Would a MANOVA be possible?

As for regression, I am struggling how to set this up. I believe logistic regression would suit the purpose. However, I am struggling to see how to set this up as this is a repeated measure of the same question. So what is even the IV here? Could someone provide me with some advice?